# Read timed out error by nzSQLException

Tags: java, netezza

While using java code with Netezza database,
getting error of `org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Read timed out`

Basically, java code generates bunch of csv files,
after each CSV file generation, CSV is loaded in netezza database.
I used below query(Java code snipped) for CSV upload

```
INSERT INTO "+table + " SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL '"
                + CSVFileName
                + "' USING ( MAXERRORS 0 DELIMITER ',' Y2BASE 2000 ENCODING 'internal' REMOTESOURCE 'JDBC' ESCAPECHAR '\' ) ";
```

This works for most of files, & then suddenly I start getting `read timed out` error.
my csv files are containing 375000 to 750000 rows (roughly28 to 56 MB file size). 
Java code uses 8 threads to create these CSVs, There is a possibility that for same table, two threads are trying to load data. Java code will run from Windows machine.
My Initial guess is that JDBC driver may have some time limit for reading CSV file.
Any idea on how can I avoid getting this error/ or any better approach.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on other files, but not on the larger ones, I can think of a few possibilities:

1. your receiving netezza box cannot receive data fast enough (though I may say that less than 100MB is not much)

   - is your target NZ system a VMware and/or behind a slow network/firewall
2. the source file is not accessible fast enough

   - McAfee or another anti virus scanner is blocking he file
   - the file is on a sloooow/overloaded disk
   - another thread in you program is blocking the file for too long (you launch the load to netezza too early)
3. the timeout is set very low

   - say 1 second

I would try to increase the timeout to 1000 seconds to see if the problem goes away and then work downwards until you find a limit.
Secondarily I would try to turn off all parallelism in the JAVA code creating the file and see if it goes away

Please let us know how it goes

Comment: It's not on slow network, & file is Frist completely written before sending to insert. Also firewall issue will cause all files to give such error but in my case out of 800 files 71 gave error. Timeout is  set to 0. So unlimited actually. I'm using jdbc driver 7.0, so now I'm trying with 7.2 to check if issue was with driver.

Comment: Happy hunting, this is NOT an easy one. Intermittent errors are the worst. About firewalls and virus scanners:  never expect them to act consistently if they act up... but many other things can cause similar issues. A non exhaustive list is windows AD servers, network switches and other components with build in failover...